# Redirect to a PORT

Tags: c, sockets, redirect, iptables

I'm redirecting the clients who are all connected to my router to another port(say 8080) using iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

I'm running executing a binary which will redirect the clients to a website. say www.google.com. I'm using the following code.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

char *reply = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n"
    "Server: Apache/2.2.3/r/n"
    "Location: http://www.google.com\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
    "\r\n";

    char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080); 


bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

printf("client connected\n");
send(connfd, reply, strlen(reply), 0);

close(connfd);
sleep(1);
}
}
```

when I doing like this the clients are not redirected. Its showing the redirected address in the address bar of the client browser. And trying for long time to goto www.google.com. and end with the following error message.

This page isn't redirecting properly.
 Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way 
 that will never complete.

I've modified the reply variable. Even now its not working as expected. 
How can i solve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, newlines should be `"\r\n"`. Secondly you do not properly terminate the header, which should be a newline after the last header field and then an extra empty line. Thirdly, you set the `Content-Length` header field to a length of 1000 bytes, which might make the client expect that the reply should have 1000 bytes in the body, which clearly it does not.